# Should you store fields and their names in a Map when using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to get certain fields by their names and I'm accessing these fields rather often. Is it good to store the fields in a `HashMap<String, Field>` if I found them once and then get them from that `HashMap` when I need them again? Or does java do something similar already and this would by totally unneccesary?

Comment: what are using reflection for in your program? Methods, Fields, Constructors ect.?

Comment: I'm currently only using it for fields but I might need to find methods in the future aswell.

Comment: Have a look at `java.beans.Introspector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid approach as there is no automated "caching" for reflection. As each reflective call consumes time caching on your own is always a good idea.